# Facebook Php SDK - getUser() return always 0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I read all threads on this forum but I can't find my solution..

I use the last Php SDK by facebook : v3.2.2 .

So I used this:

```php
//start fb
$facebook = new \Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => $fb_app_id,  
    'secret' => $fb_app_secret,  
    'cookie' => true,  
));

// get id user-fb
$fbUser = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fbUser) {
    try {
      $fbUserProfile = $facebook->api('/me'); // take user-infos
      $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); // take his friend

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
      $fbUser = null;
    }
}

if ($fbUser) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => ('my-url') ));
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'scope' => 'email,offline_access,publish_actions',
        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,email',
        'redirect_uri' => 'my-redirect-url'
        ));
}
```

So I don't understand what is wrong..
When I test it, first time I can click on the loginUrl and get authorization . but when I try to getUser again, the function `$facebook->getUser() return 0` again and I got the loginUrl again but when I click on the link, I'm just redirect on the callback url..

I'm not sure if the application facebook need special parameters for this. My app_id and app_secret are 100% sure.

Comment: Are you logged in to facebook?

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168764/facebook-getuser-always-returns-0-php-sdk-3-1-1?rq=1

Comment: yeah, I'm connected on facebook at the same time

Comment: i already try to reset app_secret in my app facebook but it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you get an access token?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/

Comment: i got one, but i need it just for got the userid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Facebook PHP SDK getUser always returning 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790272/why-is-facebook-php-sdk-getuser-always-returning-0)

Comment: i only use Php sdk, would like keep this cause i got lot of js in my website ^^ but thanks for share this

Comment: Ok i solved the error: the callback url was wrong, i needed to call the current url and not a special one.

Comment: Can you explain how you solved this problem i am also getting the same but unable to solve please help brother

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using 
`$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'public_profile',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.your_domain/current_page.php'
));`
where `'http://www.your_domain/current_page.php'` is the same page where i am running this code
N.B using Facebook php sdk 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> OK I solved the error: the callback url was wrong, I needed to call the current url and not a special one.